# How to make 5 images in a bootstrap column responsive

Tags: css, image, grid, position

I have a row with 2 columns. In second column I have 5 images with width="60px" and height="66px". How to make these 5 images be centered horizontal but to be responsive. `text-align:center` doesn't help because in smaller devices they don't look fine. They should be one under another not centered horizontal. How to make images in center of column and with the same distance between them?

Here's my code:

```css
.image {
  margin-right: 15px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   some text
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="#" class="image">
    <img src="#" class="image">
    <img src="#" class="image">
    <img src="#" class="image">
    <img src="#" class="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say exactly what you're trying to do without a working example, however have you tried simply assigning the images the `col-xs-12` class to make them full (parent) width on xs viewports?

Comment: Here's fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kgh27pch/2/   . I'm trying to make these 5images to be in the center of column and space between them to be the same. How to fix these images to have equal space between them and to the left and to the right space to be the same - to be centered?